# Odoo Error to render compiling AST, UndefinedTable

Tags: odoo, postgresql-9.5, odoo-13

I already had an database A (with Web, Sales, Invoices,...) on Odoo.com 
But now I want to use that database on local computer. So I made a backup of database A, and then restore it on localhost:8069 
The restoration was successful however when I can't connect to it.

```
Error to render compiling AST
UndefinedTable: relation "ir_attachment_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ore_fname", "type", "website_id") VALUES (nextval('ir_attach...
                                                             ^

Template: web.frontend_layout
Path: /t/html/head/t[10]
Node: <t t-call-assets="web.assets_common_minimal_js" t-css="false" defer_load="True"/>
```

And its traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "Q:\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Q:\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb._get_asset_nodes at 0x0586C4F8>, 'web.assets_common_minimal_js', 'vi_VN', False, True, '', False, True, False, (1,))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

...

Could you guys please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your database is not loading well so these models are not loaded in registry, just restore it again!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to restore it as "moved database" and "copied database" but still facing the same problem. By the way, I'm running Odoo 13.0 from their source on Github, not the Odoo installer (exe file). Does it cause problems?